# Combine Records in Temporary Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I am using SQLServer2008.

Below is my StoredProcedure

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE
(
  Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
  BrokerId INT ,
  RankId INT ,
  BrokerName VARCHAR(50) ,
  RankName VARCHAR(50) ,
  BrokerCode VARCHAR(50) ,
  IntroducerCode VARCHAR(50) ,
  CscName VARCHAR(50) ,
  SIP DECIMAL(18, 2) ,
  Fresh DECIMAL(18, 2) ,
  FY DECIMAL(18, 2) ,
  SY DECIMAL(18, 2) ,
  TY DECIMAL(18, 2)
)
DECLARE @brokerTable TABLE
(
  BrokerCode VARCHAR(50) ,
  BrokerId INT
)

INSERT  INTO @brokerTable
    ( BrokerCode, BrokerId )
    EXEC GetBrokerIdByCode @BrokerCode

DECLARE @Business TABLE ( BusinessId INT )


DECLARE @BrokerId1 INT
DECLARE @BrokerCode1 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE c1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR


SELECT  BrokerId ,BrokerCode
FROM    @brokerTable
OPEN c1


FETCH NEXT FROM c1
INTO  @BrokerId1,@BrokerCode1


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN


    INSERT  INTO @Business
            ( BusinessId 
            )
            ( SELECT    mb.BusinessId
              FROM      dbo.MemberBusiness AS mb
              WHERE     mb.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
            )           

    DECLARE @BusinessID2 INT
    DECLARE c3 CURSOR READ_ONLY
    FOR

    SELECT  BusinessId
    FROM    @Business
    OPEN c3

    FETCH NEXT FROM c3
    INTO  @BusinessID2


    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN




            INSERT  INTO @tmp
                    ( BrokerId ,
                      RankId ,
                      BrokerName ,
                      RankName ,
                      BrokerCode ,
                      IntroducerCode ,
                      CscName ,
                      SIP ,
                      Fresh ,
                      FY ,
                      SY ,
                      TY   
                      --ProBusiness ,          
                      --CscId
                    )
                    ( SELECT    @BrokerId1 ,
                                ( SELECT    RankId
                                  FROM      dbo.BrokerMaster AS bm
                                  WHERE     bm.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                ) ,
                                ( SELECT    bm.Name
                                  FROM      dbo.BrokerMaster AS bm
                                  WHERE     bm.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                ) ,
                                ( SELECT    rm.RankName
                                  FROM      dbo.RankMaster AS rm
                                  WHERE     RankId = ( SELECT
                                                          RankId
                                                       FROM
                                                          dbo.BrokerMaster
                                                          AS bm
                                                       WHERE
                                                          bm.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                     )
                                ) ,
                                @BrokerCode1 ,
                                ( SELECT    bm2.BrokerCode
                                  FROM      dbo.BrokerMaster AS bm2
                                  WHERE     bm2.BrokerId = ( SELECT
                                                          bm3.IntroducerId
                                                          FROM
                                                          dbo.BrokerMaster
                                                          AS bm3
                                                          WHERE
                                                          bm3.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                          )
                                ) ,
                                'All CSC' ,
                                ISNULL(( SELECT SUM(mb.SelfAmount)
                                                + SUM(mb.UnitAmount)
                                         FROM   dbo.MemberBusiness AS mb
                                                INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster
                                                AS pm ON mb.PlanId = pm.PlanId
                                                INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster
                                                AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
                                                INNER JOIN dbo.Installment
                                                AS i2 ON mb.InstallmentId = i2.InstallmentId
                                         WHERE  ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'true'
                                                AND mb.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                AND i2.CscId = i.CscId
                                                AND ( i2.PaymentDate >= @StartDate
                                                      AND i2.PaymentDate <= @EndDate
                                                    )
                                       ), 0) ,
                                ISNULL(( SELECT SUM(mb.SelfAmount)
                                                + SUM(mb.UnitAmount)
                                         FROM   dbo.MemberBusiness AS mb
                                                INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster
                                                AS pm ON mb.PlanId = pm.PlanId
                                                INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster
                                                AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
                                                INNER JOIN dbo.Installment
                                                AS i2 ON mb.InstallmentId = i2.InstallmentId
                                         WHERE  ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'false'
                                                AND mb.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                AND i2.InstallmentNo = 1
                                                AND i2.CscId = i.CscId
                                                AND ( i2.PaymentDate >= @StartDate
                                                      AND i2.PaymentDate <= @EndDate
                                                    )
                                       ), 0) ,
                                ( CASE WHEN ( m.Mode = 'MLY'
                                              AND ( i.InstallmentNo >= 2
                                                    AND i.InstallmentNo <= 12
                                                  )
                                            )
                                       THEN ( SELECT    SUM(mb.SelfAmount)
                                                        + SUM(mb.UnitAmount)
                                              FROM      dbo.MemberBusiness
                                                        AS mb
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster
                                                        AS pm ON mb.PlanId = pm.PlanId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster
                                                        AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Installment
                                                        AS i2 ON mb.InstallmentId = i2.InstallmentId
                                              WHERE     ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'false'
                                                        AND mb.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo >= 2
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo <= 12
                                                        AND i2.CscId = i.CscId
                                                        AND ( i2.PaymentDate >= @StartDate
                                                          AND i2.PaymentDate <= @EndDate
                                                          )
                                            )
                                       WHEN ( m.Mode = 'QLY'
                                              AND ( i.InstallmentNo >= 2
                                                    AND i.InstallmentNo <= 4
                                                  )
                                            )
                                       THEN ( SELECT    SUM(mb.SelfAmount)
                                                        + SUM(mb.UnitAmount)
                                              FROM      dbo.MemberBusiness
                                                        AS mb
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster
                                                        AS pm ON mb.PlanId = pm.PlanId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster
                                                        AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Installment
                                                        AS i2 ON mb.InstallmentId = i2.InstallmentId
                                              WHERE     ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'false'
                                                        AND mb.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo >= 2
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo <= 4
                                                        AND i2.CscId = i.CscId
                                                        AND ( i2.PaymentDate >= @StartDate
                                                          AND i2.PaymentDate <= @EndDate
                                                          )
                                            )
                                       WHEN ( m.Mode = 'HLY'
                                              AND ( i.InstallmentNo = 2 )
                                            )
                                       THEN ( SELECT    SUM(mb.SelfAmount)
                                                        + SUM(mb.UnitAmount)
                                              FROM      dbo.MemberBusiness
                                                        AS mb
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster
                                                        AS pm ON mb.PlanId = pm.PlanId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster
                                                        AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Installment
                                                        AS i2 ON mb.InstallmentId = i2.InstallmentId
                                              WHERE     ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'false'
                                                        AND mb.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo = 2
                                                        AND i2.IsReceived = 'true'
                                                        AND i2.CscId = i.CscId
                                                        AND ( i2.PaymentDate >= @StartDate
                                                          AND i2.PaymentDate <= @EndDate
                                                          )
                                            )
                                  END ) ,
                                ( CASE WHEN ( m.Mode = 'MLY'
                                              AND ( i.InstallmentNo >= 13
                                                    AND i.InstallmentNo <= 24
                                                  )
                                            )
                                       THEN ( SELECT    SUM(mb.SelfAmount)
                                                        + SUM(mb.UnitAmount)
                                              FROM      dbo.MemberBusiness
                                                        AS mb
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster
                                                        AS pm ON mb.PlanId = pm.PlanId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster
                                                        AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Installment
                                                        AS i2 ON mb.InstallmentId = i2.InstallmentId
                                              WHERE     ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'false'
                                                        AND mb.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo >= 13
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo <= 24
                                                        AND i2.CscId = i.CscId
                                                        AND ( i2.PaymentDate >= @StartDate
                                                          AND i2.PaymentDate <= @EndDate
                                                          )
                                            )
                                       WHEN ( m.Mode = 'QLY'
                                              AND ( i.InstallmentNo >= 5
                                                    AND i.InstallmentNo <= 8
                                                  )
                                            )
                                       THEN ( SELECT    SUM(mb.SelfAmount)
                                                        + SUM(mb.UnitAmount)
                                              FROM      dbo.MemberBusiness
                                                        AS mb
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster
                                                        AS pm ON mb.PlanId = pm.PlanId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster
                                                        AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Installment
                                                        AS i2 ON mb.InstallmentId = i2.InstallmentId
                                              WHERE     ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'false'
                                                        AND mb.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo >= 5
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo <= 8
                                                        AND i2.CscId = i.CscId
                                                        AND ( i2.PaymentDate >= @StartDate
                                                          AND i2.PaymentDate <= @EndDate
                                                          )
                                            )
                                       WHEN ( m.Mode = 'HLY'
                                              AND ( i.InstallmentNo >= 3
                                                    AND i.InstallmentNo <= 4
                                                  )
                                            )
                                       THEN ( SELECT    SUM(mb.SelfAmount)
                                                        + SUM(mb.UnitAmount)
                                              FROM      dbo.MemberBusiness
                                                        AS mb
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster
                                                        AS pm ON mb.PlanId = pm.PlanId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster
                                                        AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Installment
                                                        AS i2 ON mb.InstallmentId = i2.InstallmentId
                                              WHERE     ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'false'
                                                        AND mb.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo >= 3
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo <= 4
                                                        AND i2.CscId = i.CscId
                                                        AND i2.IsReceived = 1
                                                        AND ( i2.PaymentDate >= @StartDate
                                                          AND i2.PaymentDate <= @EndDate
                                                          )
                                            )
                                       WHEN ( m.Mode = 'YLY'
                                              AND ( i.InstallmentNo = 2 )
                                            )
                                       THEN ( SELECT    SUM(mb.SelfAmount)
                                                        + SUM(mb.UnitAmount)
                                              FROM      dbo.MemberBusiness
                                                        AS mb
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster
                                                        AS pm ON mb.PlanId = pm.PlanId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster
                                                        AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Installment
                                                        AS i2 ON mb.InstallmentId = i2.InstallmentId
                                              WHERE     ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'false'
                                                        AND mb.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo = 2
                                                        AND i2.CscId = i.CscId
                                                        AND ( i2.PaymentDate >= @StartDate
                                                          AND i2.PaymentDate <= @EndDate
                                                          )
                                            )
                                  END ) ,
                                ( CASE WHEN ( m.Mode = 'MLY'
                                              AND ( i.InstallmentNo >= 25 )
                                            )
                                       THEN ( SELECT    SUM(mb.SelfAmount)
                                                        + SUM(mb.UnitAmount)
                                              FROM      dbo.MemberBusiness
                                                        AS mb
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster
                                                        AS pm ON mb.PlanId = pm.PlanId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster
                                                        AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Installment
                                                        AS i2 ON mb.InstallmentId = i2.InstallmentId
                                              WHERE     ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'false'
                                                        AND mb.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo >= 25
                                                        AND i2.CscId = i.CscId
                                                        AND ( i2.PaymentDate >= @StartDate
                                                          AND i2.PaymentDate <= @EndDate
                                                          )
                                            )
                                       WHEN ( m.Mode = 'QLY'
                                              AND ( i.InstallmentNo >= 9 )
                                            )
                                       THEN ( SELECT    SUM(mb.SelfAmount)
                                                        + SUM(mb.UnitAmount)
                                              FROM      dbo.MemberBusiness
                                                        AS mb
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster
                                                        AS pm ON mb.PlanId = pm.PlanId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster
                                                        AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Installment
                                                        AS i2 ON mb.InstallmentId = i2.InstallmentId
                                              WHERE     ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'false'
                                                        AND mb.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo >= 9
                                                        AND i2.CscId = i.CscId
                                                        AND ( i2.PaymentDate >= @StartDate
                                                          AND i2.PaymentDate <= @EndDate
                                                          )
                                            )
                                       WHEN ( m.Mode = 'HLY'
                                              AND ( i.InstallmentNo >= 5 )
                                            )
                                       THEN ( SELECT    SUM(mb.SelfAmount)
                                                        + SUM(mb.UnitAmount)
                                              FROM      dbo.MemberBusiness
                                                        AS mb
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster
                                                        AS pm ON mb.PlanId = pm.PlanId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster
                                                        AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Installment
                                                        AS i2 ON mb.InstallmentId = i2.InstallmentId
                                              WHERE     ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'false'
                                                        AND mb.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo >= 5
                                                        AND i2.CscId = i.CscId
                                                        AND ( i2.PaymentDate >= @StartDate
                                                          AND i2.PaymentDate <= @EndDate
                                                          )
                                            )
                                       WHEN ( m.Mode = 'YLY'
                                              AND ( i.InstallmentNo >= 3 )
                                            )
                                       THEN ( SELECT    SUM(mb.SelfAmount)
                                                        + SUM(mb.UnitAmount)
                                              FROM      dbo.MemberBusiness
                                                        AS mb
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster
                                                        AS pm ON mb.PlanId = pm.PlanId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster
                                                        AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Installment
                                                        AS i2 ON mb.InstallmentId = i2.InstallmentId
                                              WHERE     ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'false'
                                                        AND mb.BrokerId = @BrokerId1
                                                        AND i2.InstallmentNo >= 3
                                                        AND i2.CscId = i.CscId
                                                        AND ( i2.PaymentDate >= @StartDate
                                                          AND i2.PaymentDate <= @EndDate
                                                          )
                                            )
                                  END )
                      FROM      dbo.MemberBusiness AS mb
                                INNER JOIN dbo.Member AS m ON mb.MemberId = m.MemberId
                                INNER JOIN dbo.Installment AS i ON mb.InstallmentId = i.InstallmentId
                                INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster AS pm ON mb.PlanId = pm.PlanId
                                INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
                      WHERE     mb.BusinessId = @BusinessID2
                      GROUP BY  i.InstallmentNo ,
                                m.Mode ,
                                i.CscId
                    )

            FETCH NEXT FROM c3
            INTO  @BusinessID2

        END
    CLOSE c3
    DEALLOCATE c3

    DELETE  FROM @Business

    FETCH NEXT FROM c1
INTO  @BrokerId1,@BrokerCode1

END
CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1



SELECT  t.BrokerId ,
    t.FY ,
    t.SY ,
    t.TY
FROM    @tmp AS t
```

And output is :

```
--------------------------------------------
 BrokerId |    FY    |    SY    |    TY    |
--------------------------------------------
    27    |   500    |    NULL  |   NULL   |
--------------------------------------------
    27    |   500    |    200   |   NULL   |
--------------------------------------------
    27    |   500    |    NULL  |   100    |
--------------------------------------------
```

But I want to output in 1 record like :

```
--------------------------------------------
 BrokerId |    FY    |    SY    |    TY    |
--------------------------------------------
    27    |   500    |    200   |   100    |
--------------------------------------------
```

How can I do that please help me..Thanks.

Comment: What if your data's different in different columns?  Or can we assume that `FY`, `SY` and `TY` will always have the same value (though for different brokers)?

Comment: No, FY,SY and TY may have different values

Comment: In that case your request is pointless - you may have a single broker with multiple values!  As an example, what if broker 27 has FY=500, SY=NULL and TY=100 in one row, FY=600, SY=NULL and TY=200 in the second, and FY=600, SY=400 and TY=NULL in the third? How do we know which to group together?

Comment: The sample data looks like you want the maximum in each column. If the second row had FY = 400 instead of FY = 500, what would you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your're able to integrate this CTE into your SP:

```
WITH CTE AS ( 
  SELECT BrokerId,
         RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY BrokerId ORDER BY BrokerID),
         FY=MIN(FY)OVER(PARTITION BY BrokerId),
         SY=MIN(SY)OVER(PARTITION BY BrokerId),
         TY=MIN(TY)OVER(PARTITION BY BrokerId)
         FROM   dbo.Broker )
SELECT BrokerId, FY, SY, TY  FROM  CTE  WHERE  RN = 1
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b711/7/0)

Comment: Thanks..It is very helpful for me..but what if i want display Total of FY,SY and TY?

Comment: @Prashant16: _Total_ means the sum of FY+SY+TY? Btw, if you want the maximum values of each value you have to replace `MIN` with `MAX` in my query. I've assumed that you simply want a non-null value.

Comment: Yes @TimSchmelter : I want to sum of FY+SY+TY.

Comment: @Prashant16: Just add `[SUM] = FY+SY+TY` to the select. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b711/11/0

Answer (score 0):

Change the last select statement to:

```
SELECT  t.BrokerId ,
    t.FY ,
    t.SY ,
    SUM(t.TY) as TY
FROM    @tmp AS t
GROUP BY t.FY, t.SY
```